# How to change plot3 colors in octave?

Tags: 3d, plot, octave

I am trying to plot three series of 3d data on a single plot. I need to use colours, which even if the plot is printed in grey scale will be readable. I cannot make octave to display the plot in colours I've selected. I tried through format strings like '-r', I tried by setting name-value pair in plot3 command, and tried using set with handle returned from plot command.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
t=0:0.01:10;

x1=sin(t);
y1=cos(t);

x2=sin(2*t);
y2=cos(2*t);

x3=t.*sin(t);
y3=t.*cos(t);
figure;
clf;
hold on;
plot3(x1,y1,t,'-b','lineWidth',1);
plot3(x2,y2,t,'-r','lineWidth',3);
plot3(x3,y3,t,'-k','lineWidth',5);

xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('t');

legend(' sin(t) cos(t)','sin(2t) cos(2t)','t*sin(t) t*cos(t)');
print('-dpng','sweetSOExample.png');
```

[image: Plot from the example script]

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the problem exactly. The 3 lines appear with 3 different colours. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I want to get lines in colors: red,  blue, black. In that order.

Comment: your code works just fine for me. I get the right colours and can change it fine. What octave version are you using? Maybe it's a bug in an old version. I'm using 3.6.2.

Comment: I am also using 3.6.2...

Comment: hmmm.... Could it be a bug related to the graphics toolkit you're using? What does `graphics_toolkit` return? If it doesn't return `fltk` (the one I'm using), try `graphics_toolkit fltk` before running your minimal example. I get 3 lines colored in blue (`-b`), red (`-r`)  and black (`-k`).

Comment: My `graphics_toolkit` is `gnuplot`. After setting `fltk` it did print the lines as it should. Yet I'd rather use `gnuplot`. Anyway, thanks for help! :)